# F# breaking from while loop in complex statements

Tags: f#

I have such a function:

```
let ScanColors() =
    for i in 1..54 do
        let mutable c = Unchecked.defaultof<string>

        if (i = 9) then 
            c <- "U - WHITE"
        else
            if (i <> 0 && i%9 = 0) then 
                MoveSensor(SensorPos.THIRD)
            else
                MoveSensor(
                    match ((i - (i/9)*9)%2 <> 0) with 
                        | true -> SensorPos.SECOND
                        | false -> SensorPos.FIRST)

            while (true) do
                c <- ScanColor()
                if (c = "ERR") then
                    CalibrateSensorPosition()
                else
                   break
            ResetSensorPosition()
```

in this function, in the `while`statement, I cannot use break, because as you know, `break` is not used in F#. I was looking for alternatives for `break`, and I saw this link:

[F# break from while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543548/f-break-from-while-loop)

But to be honest, I couldn't be sure whether this solution suits with my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly F# does not support `break`. There are various fairly complicated ways to deal with this (like [this recent one](http://latkin.org/blog/2014/12/26/nested-looping-to-programmatic-depth-in-f/) or my [computation builder](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-ii-break.aspx/)), but those have disadvantages and make your code fairly complex.

The general way to deal with this is to rewrite the code using recursion - this will typically compile to the same IL as what you would write in C# using `break` and `continue`.

So, the `while` block in your snippet could be written as a function that calls itself recursively until the result is not "ERR" and then returns the `c`:

```
let rec scanWhileErr () =     
  let c = ScanColor()
  if c = "ERR" then
    CalibrateSensorPosition()
    scanWhileErr()
  else c
```

And then call this function from the main block:

```
if (i <> 0 && i%9 = 0) then 
  MoveSensor(SensorPos.THIRD)
else
  MoveSensor(if (i - (i/9)*9)%2 <> 0 then SensorPos.SECOND else SensorPos.FIRST)

c <- scanWhileErr ()
ResetSensorPosition()
```

Aside, I also changed your `match` on Booleans into an ordinary `if` - when you have just two cases and they are Booleans, there is really no point in using `match` over `if`.

Also, I kept your mutable variable `c`, but I suspect that you no longer need it thanks to recursion.

Comment: Tomas, the sequence of my functions are important. For instance, I have to use the functions in if - else first, then I have to write my while loop. Your solution is perfect, but if I implement this, the sequence of my events are changing. For instance, I have to call MoveSensor() function before calling CalibrateSensorPosition(). How can we implement the approach according to the sequence?

Comment: You can define this as local function and call it from the right place in your main function. I believe my snippet preserves your order of calls...

Answer (score 6):

*Break* does not exist in F#, personally I would try to avoid breaks even in C# as there are many alternative/cleaner ways to break a loop.

A simple fix while keeping your imperative code style will be this:

```
c <- ScanColor()
while (c = "ERR") do
    CalibrateSensorPosition()
    c <- ScanColor()
ResetSensorPosition()
```

But in F# it can be further compacted to this one-liner:

```
while (c <- ScanColor(); c = "ERR") do CalibrateSensorPosition()
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think this approach is fine, and worked in my case:

```
        let mutable flag = true
        while (flag = true) do
            c <- ScanColor()
            if (c = "ERR") then
                CalibrateSensorPosition()
            else
               flag <- false
        ResetSensorPosition()
```

Comment: Yes, using a (mutable) flag will do the job as well. But you don't need `= true` inside the while condition, it's redundant. You can write just `while flag do`

Comment: Not downvoting, but I would not consider mutability "fine" when other, more idiomatic, options are available and just as easy. I wouldn't let this pass a code review at work. ;-]

Comment: I agree with @ildjarn except that I would accept it momentarily if it's a translation from C# code or another language. Once the translation is finished and fully tested and accepted I would consider refactoring to more f#-ish style and remove unnecessary mutables.

Comment: I think this portrait the intent of the code with more clarity. Mutability is ok when is localized and contained.

Answer (score 0):

I think that an easy way is when it happen that you need to have a "break" in a loop then you just make sure that the loop terminate.

an example of this could be that if we have a while loop that look like this

```
while i < upperlimit do
   if a
   then break
```